# Is there a *lower* precision TimeSpan in .NET?

Tags: .net, time, timespan

The .NET `TimeSpan` struct uses an `Int64` to store `Ticks`, offering 100 nanosecond precision and a maximum value of around 60,000 **years**.

In my application, I am working with huge numbers of objects, perhaps 100,000, each of which has two associated `TimeSpan` properties BUT I only need precision to around 0.1 seconds, and a maximum value of around 10 hours. (I'm timing audio recordings, not the radioactive decay of uranium.)

I want the functionality of `TimeSpan`, but I'd like to use only 4 bytes rather than 8, to save memory, given the large number of instances and no need for the massive extra range and precision.

Is there anything like this, or would I have to roll my own?

Comment: For 100k objects with two timespans each, for 8 bytes per timespan, it gives a grand-total of around 1.6MB, hardly any trouble for any computer nowadays. The CLR alone would consume far more than this. I don't find any need to optimize memory usage here.

Comment: There's `TimeOfDay` proposed for .NET 6, but the precision/size has not yet been defined - see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/49036); honestly, though, I'd probably roll my own here - and I do so quite often; as in, use a `ushort` / `uint` / whatever (I guess `uint` here, to cover the range) in a *field*, and have a *property* that exposes it as a scaled `TimeSpan`

Comment: @Alejandro: Fair point. Maybe I'm optimizing prematurely.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Interesting. I hadn't heard about that. You're probably right that rolling my own as you suggest would be straightforward enough.